# visual studio 2012 takes very long time to run any project for first time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

When I run any project solution for first time; it takes very long time to load. 
On the bottom status bar it shows its load numbers of dll's, few also from temp folder (which I think is quite unnecessary) {It takes somewhat like 5-7 min to load all those dll's}

After that a popup opens saying "Attempting to cancel will disable further symbol loading", which takes additional around 4-5 mins.

But while running project second time, it run fast (no loading as in first time)

[image]

AND same project file on other machine loads very fast.

Is there any way, that I can disable these unnecessary loading?

I have also full-scaned my pc, to check if its due to any spam or virus infection.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Visual Studio not to load Symbols for external (typically MS, but if you have a corporate Symbol Server you might also have other library code) code - this will speed up the run time, but it does mean you won't be able to "step-into" core Framework code:

Tools | Options | Debugging | Symbols:

[image: Debugging Symbols page]

You can either clear the check-box entirely, or set it to "Only specified modules" for the .dlls you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.
Does it effect my project performance if I set to "Only Specified modules" option??

Comment: Nope - it's purely for loading the debugging symbols.